# Passing user's response in next bot response

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, dialogflow-es

I want a bot to send a personalized response by fetching the exact user's sentence asked previously. For example:

- DialogFlow: *What are you eating?*
- User: *I am eating waffles with strawberry flavor but I'm hungry again.*
- DialogFlow: *Okay, But why are you eating "I am eating waffles with strawberry flavor but I'm hungry again."?*

The above is just a reference, but I want the user's response to being fed into next bot question.

Comment: you can save it in session and use it in next query. where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 2):

**1. Extract your parameter**

User> *I am eating `waffles with strawberry flavor` but I'm hungry again.*

Mark `waffles with strawberry flavor` in your parameters e.g. with the key `food`.

**2. Use it in your response**

Dialogflow> *Okay, But why are you eating $food?*

---

Please consult the documentation. [Referring to Parameter Values in Responses](https://dialogflow.com/docs/actions-and-parameters#referring_to_parameter_values_in_responses).

And if you want to use the parameter later again with the help of contexts refer to this documentation page:  [Extracting Parameter Values from Contexts](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts#extracting_parameter_values_from_contexts).

Answer (score 2):

It depends how much of the user's response you want.

If you just want a portion and can deal with some text that you don't need to handle, you can set a [parameter](https://dialogflow.com/docs/actions-and-parameters) with the [system entity type](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities#system_entities) of `@sys.any`.

You can use these parameters directly in the [Response](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents#response) that you edit using the Intent editor.

So you might have an Intent that looks something like this:

[image]

If you actually want the entire phrase, you may be tempted to make the entire training phrase a `@sys.any` parameter, but this will have mixed results.

In these cases, you may need to use a [fulfillment webhook](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment) and turn on fulfillment for your [Fallback Intent](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents#fallback_intents) which captures anything not captured elsewhere. You don't indicate what library you might be using, but if you're looking at the JSON sent to you, the entire text would be in `queryResult.queryText`. If you're using the dialogflow-fulfillment library, you can use the `agent.query()` method.